# Internal Server Error при вызове in_array

Tags: php

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой, когда вызов `in_array` на большом массиве (500 000 элементов) выдает `internal Server Error`? Вызывается внутри перебора `RecursiveIteratorIterator` в цикле `foreach`.

Comment: Все сталкивались. in_array на большом массиве (500 000 элементов) - это адъ.

Comment: @Ипатьев, есть другие варианты?

Comment: Да, разумеется. Не обрабатывать в РНР скрипте гигазы данных. Для этого есть БД

Comment: @Ипатьев, это не мой случай, так как нужно перебрать файлы на сервере и удалить лишние - те, что отсутствуют в той же БД, откуда считываю такой массив. 500 000 запросов к БД загрузят еще сильнее.

Comment: Нет, не загрузят. Тем более что число можно значительно сократить. Пишите изначальную задачу, вам расскажут как ее правильно решать.

Comment: Как вариант, делать не массив значений, а массив `key=>false` и проверять вхождение по ключу `if($myArray[$searchKey]!==null)` вместо `in_array`. Либо использовать расширение DS со структурой Set (http://php.net/manual/ru/class.ds-set.php)